# NAudio trimming mp3 file

Tags: wpf, audio, trim, naudio

I'm trying to trim a mp3 file. 
using this code:

```
private void TrimMp3(string open, string save)
    {
        using (var mp3FileReader = new Mp3FileReader(open))
        using (var writer = File.Create(save))
        {
            var startPostion = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            var endPostion = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
            mp3FileReader.CurrentTime = startPostion;
            while (mp3FileReader.CurrentTime < endPostion)
            {
                var frame = mp3FileReader.ReadNextFrame();
                if (frame == null) break;
                writer.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

"open" is the file I'm trimming and "save" is the location I'm saving.
The trimming works but not fully. The new file does start from 60 seconds but it keeps going and not stopping at 90 seconds. For example if the file is 3 minutes it will start at 1 minute and end at 3. Its like the while is always true. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your `Mp3FileReader` is doing there. But your `while loop` looks odd. Does `mp3FileRead.ReadNextFrame()` also change `mp3FileReader.CurrentTime` ? If not then there is your problem.
You should atleast do `mp3FileReader.CurrentTime` + 1Frame. Otherwise your currenttime is never changed and loop will always be `true`

Comment: I think it should. I'ts from the library NAudio. I'm learning through Mark Heath course (the author of NAudio) and thats the code he wrote but instead of giving file location for open and save he made it defult.

Comment: @EldarGoren Can you link to documentation ?

Comment: Do you mean NAudio documentation? if so :https://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: you said it was the code Mark wrote, is that where he is trimming a WAV file ?  http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.nl/2009/09/trimming-wav-file-using-naudio.html

Comment: I'm learning through pluralsight. He made videos in there.https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/audio-programming-naudio/table-of-contents

but its costs money so I don't think you will be able to see it.

Comment: Have you check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14169073/2289942

Answer (score 0):

In NAudio 1.8.0, `Mp3FileReader.ReadNextFrame` does not progress `CurrentTime`, although I [checked in a fix](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/commit/42ebd73b020637d1b7410fb643ec7b19bd0f11c8) for that recently.

So you can either get the latest NAudio code, or make use of the `SampleCount` property on each `Mp3Frame` to accurately keep track of how far through you are yourself.

Comment: I'm already using NAudio 1.8.0
I'm pretty new to this so there is a way that I can download the fix? If not ill try mess with the sample count.

Comment: I added position variable to the code like you did in the fix.


`var position = 0;
                while (mp3FileReader.CurrentTime < endPosition)
                {
                    var frame = mp3FileReader.ReadNextFrame();
                    if (frame == null) break;
                    writer.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
                    position += frame.SampleCount * mp3FileReader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample;
                }`



how do I add position to the `mp3FileReader.CurrentTIme` to fix the while?