# play mp3 frame by frame

Tags: c#, .net, stream, mp3, naudio

I need to play mp3 frames, which are transmitted via network using UDP.

I found a way to split an mp3 into frames using NAudio [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094287/naudio-to-split-mp3-file).

A way to play frames using NAudio would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The [NAudio source code](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) comes with a demo showing exactly how to do this. Look in the `NAudioDemo` project, in the `Mp3StreamingDemo` folder.