# MP3 splitting - output files don't have correct file info

Tags: c#, split, mp3, naudio

I have successfully used code from following SO question:
[NAudio to split mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094287/naudio-to-split-mp3-file) to split some test MP3s.

The input file has constant bitrate 198kbps. The debug shows, that splitting occurs at correct time (each 120 seconds).

The problem is, that Windows and audioplayer show incorrect information about the files. The bitrate vary and the file duration too.

What I need to do, to correct the ingfo in output files?

Comment: Is this a VBR file?  198kbit is not a standard bitrate.  Also, you can't simply split on frames, since some frames may contain data from other frames, also known as the bit reservoir.

Comment: The audio player (AIMP) shows whole time of playing the mp3 the 198kbps, so I estimated it is actually an CBR file. Is there any more precise way to get the bitrate?

Comment: What you have is actually a VBR file, and it is showing you the average bitrate.