# What is the proper way to split mp3 audio in MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, audio, mp3

I have a `MemoryStream` that reads in audio from online and then saves it to `FileStream`. The audio playback plays fine with the one problem that the first 30-40 milliseconds of the clip is dead sound and silent at the beginning of each split. This is problematic because I need to divide audio clips into multiple files to later seamlessly be played. **Is there a certain byte or hex in mp3 data that indicates where a frame of an mp3 starts/finishes to try and split it at the right position?** What might this look like in code?

In this simple `FileStream` save here, you can see that in my experimenting even if I try to clip out that dead spot at the beginning, it still creates deadspace - leading me to think I am splitting the sound file at an incorrect position and then the player cannot read that frame - but how can I overcome this?

```
byte[] byteArray = ms.ToArray();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destPath + filename + ".mp3", FileMode.Create))
{
        fs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
```

Clipping back to try and get rid of that dead space at beginning just to test:

```
byte[] oldArray = ms.ToArray();
byte[] newArray = new byte[oldArray.Length - 1000];
Array.Copy(oldArray, 1000, newArray, 0, newArray.Length);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destPath + filename + ".mp3", FileMode.Create))
{
      fs.Write(newArray, 0, newArray.Length);
 }
```

[image]

Inspecting the byte array of the mp3 being saved, there is data being saved even in that dead space when I convert it to text but for some reason it just doesn't play. As I said, I'm guessing it is something to do with the file being split incorrectly half way through a sound frame or something? Sorry if I have used incorrect terminology.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to take a look here:
[NAudio to split mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094287/naudio-to-split-mp3-file).
NAudio is a complete library, could be for you ...