# Using Twilio APIs, how can I record a meeting in separate files with start and stop recording within a single room?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, audio-recording, recording, video-recording

Is it possible to obtain separate recording files using Twilio's  API when utilizing start and stop recording functionality within a single meeting room?
I would like to have distinct recording files for specific time intervals during the live meeting.

For instance, I wish to generate one recording file for the first 15 minutes of the meeting and another recording file for the subsequent 20 minutes. Is this achievable with Twilio's API, and if so, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The Twilio API does not have this type of capability built-in. You would need to build your own process to monitor the time and then at the desired interval make a call to the Twilio REST API to stop/start the recording. This probably won't be super accurate and you will likely lose a few seconds of conversation because the participants may talk through your desired intervals and your process and the Twilio REST Api will take time to respond.

If I was going to try and do this I would use either an [Azure Queue with an initialvisibilitydelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage?view=azure-dotnet) or an [Azure Function with a Timer Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp). But, I don't think either approaches would be easy to implement or super accurate.

Another option is to collect the full recording and then process it after the call ends into the desired segments. Take the MP3 file and split it. This would cause no lost audio and you could get exact intervals. A library such as [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) could do that as shown in this [NAudio to Split MP3 File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094287/naudio-to-split-mp3-file).