# How split mp3 using Naudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

How can i cut a certain time of mp3 file and convert it to wave with **N audio** with out save any file in hard disk? (i want result in byte array!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Refer Following Code:**

```
string nMP3Folder = "FOLDER PATH";
string nMP3SourceFilename = "SOURCE MP3 FILENAME";
string nMP3OutputFilename = "YOUR OUTPUT MP3 FILENAME";

using (Mp3FileReader rdr = new Mp3FileReader(nMP3Folder + nMP3SourceFilename))
{
    int count = 1;
    Mp3Frame objmp3Frame = reader.ReadNextFrame();
    System.IO.FileStream _fs = new System.IO.FileStream(nMP3Folder + nMP3OutputFilename, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);

    while (objmp3Frame != null)
    {
        if (count > 500) //retrieve a sample of 500 frames
            return;

        _fs.Write(objmp3Frame.RawData, 0, objmp3Frame.RawData.Length);
        count = count + 1;
        objmp3Frame = rdr.ReadNextFrame();
     }

     _fs.Close();
}
```

**Also refer following question to get more links:**

[Trim an MP3 Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551074/trim-an-mp3-programatically)